# Toggle a plugin with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm using a plugin that simulates snowfall. I want the user to be able to trigger this on and off. I can get toggle to start the snowfall, I'm just not sure how to turn it off. Here's what I got:

```
    // LET IT SNOW
    $('.let-it-snow').toggle(function(){
        $('body').snowfall({flakeCount : 50});
    }, function(){
        //this is the part I need help with...
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use this [plugin](http://www.somethinghitme.com/2010/12/09/jquery-snowfall-plugin-1-4/):

```
// LET IT SNOW
$('.let-it-snow').toggle(function(){
    $('body').snowfall({flakeCount : 50});
}, function(){
    $('body').snowfall('clear');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I was apparently using an old version of the plugin which I do not believe had this support.

Comment: Yeah I didn't add clearing until a bit later on, nice catch :).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using snowfall version >= 1.3 you can use:

```
$('body').snowfall('clear');
```

To stop the effect.

Answer (score 2):

As par the plugin API you can stop snow fall. Ex:

```
$(document).snowfall('clear');
$('#elementid').snowfall('clear');
$('.class').snowfall('clear');
```

So you just need to do:

```
$('body').snowfall('clear');
```